# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

```
declare @collist nvarchar(max)

SET @Collist = STUFF((SELECT ',[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Sales'
AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('User_1','User_2','User_3','User_4')
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')


EXECUTE sp_executesql @collist
```

why am I  getting the below error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: `PRINT` `@Collist` before executing it - it just contains a list of comma-separated column names. **not** a complete query.

Comment: everything looks fine... but while running it I keep on getting this error

Comment: Everything doesn't look fine, and I can say that without even knowing your table/columns. `@colList` contains a string like `column1, column2, column3`, and you're passing that to `sp_executesql`. The *first* diagnostic step when constructing SQL on the fly like this should be to *print out the SQL you've generated*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query generated by `@Collist` is not valid SQL, and it can't be executed using `sp_executesql`

You are missing `SELECT` and also `FROM`

Change it like following.

```
declare @collist nvarchar(max)

SET @Collist = 'SELECT ' +  STUFF((SELECT ',[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Sales'
AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('User_1','User_2','User_3','User_4')
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') + ' FROM Sales'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @collist
```

One observation, instead of using `[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']'` you can use `QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)`

Using `QUOTENAME`, your query should look like.

```
declare @collist nvarchar(max)

SET @Collist = 'SELECT ' +  STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + '' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Sales'
AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('User_1','User_2','User_3','User_4')
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') + 'FROM [Sales]'


EXECUTE sp_executesql @collist
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to support generic column names -- even those with non-standard characters (i.e. need to be escaped).

To handle this properly, you need two things:

1. Use `QUOTENAME()` for quoting the identifier name.
2. Handle special characters in XML, by using the `TYPE` option.

You can do this as:

```
DECLARE @collist nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Collist = STUFF( (SELECT ', ', QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)
                       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                       WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Sales' AND
                             COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('User_1', 'User_2', 'User_3', 'User_4')
                       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                      ).VALUE('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'
                             ), 1, 2, ''
                   );

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT ' + @collist + ' FROM Sales';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: We are getting below error for this query:          Msg 227, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
"VALUE" is not a valid function, property, or field.

Comment: @philipsStalin . .  `.value()` should be working.  That is how XML works.